# Get request body from node.js's http.IncomingMessage

Tags: node.js, httprequest, httpserver

I'm trying to implement a simple HTTP endpoint for an application written in node.js. I've created the HTTP server, but now I'm stuck on reading the request content body:

```
http.createServer(function(r, s) {
    console.log(r.method, r.url, r.headers);
    console.log(r.read());
    s.write("OK"); 
    s.end(); 
}).listen(42646);
```

Request's method, URL and headers are printed correctly, but `r.read()` is always NULL. I can say it's not a problem in how the request is made, because `content-length` header is greater than zero on server side.

[Documentation says](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) `r` is a `http.IncomingMessage` object that implements the Readable Stream interface, so why it's not working?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the solution. The `r` stream (like everything else in node.js, stupid me...) should be read in an async event-driven way:

```
http.createServer(function(r, s) {
    console.log(r.method, r.url, r.headers);
    var body = "";
    r.on('readable', function() {
        body += r.read();
    });
    r.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);
        s.write("OK"); 
        s.end(); 
    });
}).listen(42646);
```

Comment: It's not only an asynchronous approach but also event driven. The fact that you can operate effectively with functions and you are able to pass them as first-class functions and you can work with closures (anonymous functions),  makes this method the most important programming method in javascript. Anyway I would prefer `r.on("data",function(chunk))` where you can directly work with the read data. In contrast to `readable`, `data` signals that something has been read from the stream, not that something can be read. And that is the preferred way for a io anyway.

Comment: @BigMan73 is right - this will add a null to the end of the body string. Look at his answer instead.

Answer (score 44):

'readable' event is wrong, it incorrectly adds an extra null character to the end of the body string

Processing the stream with chunks using 'data' event:

```
http.createServer((r, s) => {
    console.log(r.method, r.url, r.headers);
    let body = '';
    r.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });
    r.on('end', () => {
        console.log(body);
        s.write('OK'); 
        s.end(); 
    });
}).listen(42646);
```

Answer (score 6):

From the official documentation
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction

```js
let body = [];
request.on('data', (chunk) => {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
});
```

If you want to use await you can convert it to a promise like that:

```js
// how to call function:
const body = await getBody(request);

// function:
function getBody(request) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const bodyParts = [];
    let body;
    request.on('data', (chunk) => {
      bodyParts.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
      body = Buffer.concat(bodyParts).toString();
      resolve(body)
    });
  });
}
```