# github apps - webhook request doesn't have payload

Tags: express, github-api, webhooks

First, here are my github apps events:
[image]

And I set up my webhook URL(`blahblah.com/watch`) and express server like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.post("/watch", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("opened"));
```

The problem is that when I create an issue comment, the request of webhook arrives in my express server but has no **body or payload**.

The request is here:

[image]

#### LOOK AT THAT! THERE IS NO PAYLOAD!

What should I do? What am I doing wrong?

I thought `req` must have a property `body` or `payload`. How can I access the payload of the request?

Comment: Since you're using Node, I'd really recommend using [Probot](https://github.com/probot/probot) for processing webhooks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is not because of webhook request, but my express code!

I've resolved the problem by modifying my code like this:

```
app.post("/watch", (req, res) => {
    let body = "";
    req.on("readable", () => {
        body += req.read();
    });
    req.on("end", () => {
        console.log(body);
    })
});
```

I didn't know that there is `readable` event and `end` event to handle a request!

I've got an idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31007121/6388746).