# Read Body from IncomingMessage Object in a Google Cloud Function with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function based on node.js 8 and I'd like to process the body of the `IncomingMessage` object. I can't access the body via `req.body` as lined out in the [Google Examples](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http?hl=de#writing_http_helloworld-nodejs). I get `req.body` is undefined.

If I log the `req` object, I get an `IncomingMessage` object, hence I try to read the body as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006711/get-request-body-from-node-jss-http-incomingmessage) and I end up with the following implementation.

```
'use strict';

exports.insertSuccessfulConsent = (req, res) => {
    console.log(`METHOD: ${req.method}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(req.headers)}`);

    let body = "";

    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString(); 
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
        console.log(body);
    });

    console.log('Body: ' + body); 


    let message = 'POST processed';
    res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

Unfortunately the body is empty, although the HTTP POST request has data in the body. This is my test call:

`curl -X POST HTTP_TRIGGER_ENDPOINT -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"name":"Jane"}'`

Headers and HTTP Methods are correct in the log, only the body is missing.

Question is: How to I get the Body from the req object?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but in the example written by Google they are referencing `Express` and you referenced a solution for an issue with NodeJS plain `http` module. I'm not sure if it fits here, despite that being used by `express` itself.

Is your listener for the 'data' event even being called? If not, that's the reason why your `body` is empty, you defined it as empty before and your listener never got called by the `data` event.

The reason why your `req.data` is set as `undefined` is probably because it is `undefined` by default in `Express`. You will need a parser as `express` points out on its [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req).

You can use something like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module for populating your `req.body`.

I hope it helps.